# Conditionally set PATH in .zshrc based off what's run in Terminal

Tags: zshrc

Suppose I am in the Terminal and run a specific command:

`> my_command`

What I'd like to do is set my PATH in .zshrc only if `my_command` is run from the Terminal.

Basically, I am looking for something else this:

```
if [[ <check to see if my_command was entered in Terminal> ]]; then
    export PATH="/my/path/bin:$PATH"
fi
```

I am unsure what to put for `<check to see if my_command was entered in Terminal>` .

Comment: Do you mean "detect if I'm using a login shell"? The `.zshrc` is run when your shell is initialized, not on any given command.